# Is this a partial order relation?

Tags: relations, order-theory

Let $\;C$ = set of cities.
The relation $\,S=\big\{(x,y)\;|\;x\in C\text{ and }y\in C$ are less than $50$ miles from each other$\big\}$
to me understanding is :

1. ***reflexive***: all cities are less than $50$ miles from themselves
2. ***symmetry***: if $x$ is less than $50$ miles from $y$, then $y$ must also be less be $50$ miles from $x$, but $y$ does not need to be igual $x$
3. ***not transitive***：if $x$ is less than $50$ miles from $y$ and $y$ is less than $50$ miles from $z$, then $x$ might not be less than $50$ miles from $z$.
   For example:
   $x-y = 20$ miles
   $y-z = 40$ miles
   $x-z = 60$ miles

Answer (score 2):

Partial Order is reflexive, Antisymmetric and transitive.

**Antisimmetry**$:\big((a,b) \in S \big)\land \big((b,a) \in S \big) \Rightarrow a=b
$

which in this case seems not to be true because of symmetric property you mentioned.

Note that I don't know what set you are working with, but an example where symmetry need not hold would be directed graphs, because path from **a** to **b** is not necessarily equal to path from **b** to **a**.

but it's obviously not transitive so no, **it's not a partial order**.

Comment: Notice that if every city in $C$ is more than 50 miles from any other city, then $S=C^2$ and it is both an equivalence relation and order (it is equality; the order would be an anti-chain), but otherwise, you pointed out the main reason for which the OP was not in the right path (symmetry instead of anti-symmetry). (+1)